# Using git for deployment with preexisting untracked code on production server

Tags: git, deployment

So I have a production server with code that is out of date and I have a remote git repository  with up to date code.

What I want to do is get all of the up to date code onto my production server without deleting stuff like uploads that only exist on the server.

What's the best way to do this? I have git init'ed on my production server, added the remote and done git fetch --all. I just need to know what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution to this. If I initialise a repository on my production server and then fetch from my remote repository, I can call `git reset --hard origin/branch` and it will checkout the branch leaving alone everything that is new.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a full backup, you should be safe to simply `cp -r git-DIR/* production-DIR/` To copy over the up to date content along with `.git`. You'll then likely want to add all the DIR's containing the uploaded data to your [.gitignore](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html).

Comment: Thanks very much, I'd be very interested to know if it's possible to do this using just git though. Because this method will require me to clone the repo to another location on the server first before copying over.